# Bridging two ethernet connections

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have two network cards/interfaces: enp5s0 (which is connected to a 15m distant router connected to the internet) and enp4s0 (which is connected to another router not connected to the internet). I would like to use enp4s0 router wifi to extend enp5s0 internet connection. I tried to successfully create a bridged connection but when I connect to enp4s0's wifi I still can't connect to the Internet. Any hint?

Comment: Hint: search for `Linux gateway iptables`